# why onclick is working only at the time of first click and stops working after that?

Tags: javascript, html

Why when I click on the `div` element first time its working and the `background-color` is changed but on second time its not changing back?

```html
<body>
<div id="box1" onclick="changeBack(Colors[0], 'box1')" ondragenter=""></div>

<script>
var Colors = ["white"];

function changeBack (color, id) {
    
    if (color === "white") {
        color = "black";
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "black";
    } else if (color === "black") {
        color = "white";
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Because you're always calling the function with `Colors[0]` which is always `"white"`, so you always go through the `if (color === "white")` path in the code.

Comment: You are forcing white color !

Comment: But in that if statement its changing to black or not?

Comment: The parameter that gets passed to the function never changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the handler this way:

```
 onclick="changeBack(Colors[0], 'box1')"
```

you can simplify to:

```
onclick="changeBack(this)"
```

The **this** keyword refers to current element, in your case box1.

In order to change color you can simply test the value of current backgroundColor:

```js
function changeBack (ele) {
  var color = (ele.style.backgroundColor || 'white') == 'white' ? 'black' : 'white';
  ele.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
div {
    border: thick solid #0000FF;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" onclick="changeBack(this)" ondragenter=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div id="box1" data-state="white"></div>

<script>
const div= document.getElementById('box1');
div.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    const state = div.getAttribute('data-state');
    const newState = state == "white" ? "black":"white";
    div.style.backgroundColor = newState;
    div.setAttribute('data-state', newState);
});

</script>
</body>
```